# how to add user in facebook group using pre-approved

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are trying to add other facebook user in our private facebook group, But we don't get any API for that also we heard about "Pre-Approved" user, But not getting details as much.

Basically we have one form in that we ask our user to put their facebook email address and after that we need add those user in our facebook group.

Please let me know if there any way.

Comment: there is no api for that

Comment: Okay, Is there any alternate way to achieve?

Comment: no, if there is no api for it, then you can only do it manually